# Merge two hashes and return common data

Tags: ruby, hash

I have two hashes:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
```

I need to return hash such as:

```
h3 = { 
  "a" => { "h1" => 100, "h2" => nil},
  "b" => { "h1" => 200, "h2" => 254},
  "c" => { "h1" => nil, "h2" => 300}
}
```

I am trying to use:

```
h1.merge(h2) { |k, val, old| { 'h1' => val, 'h2' => old } }
```

but it return only:

```
{"a"=>100, "b"=>{"h1"=>200, "h2"=>254}, "c"=>300}
```

without nil.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the official document for `merge` ([here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-merge)) it say:

> the value for each duplicate key is determined by calling the block
>   with the key, its value in hsh and its value in other_hash.

This means for keys `"a"` and `"c"` , the block is never called (as they are not duplicate keys), as a result you are missing `nil` in your result hash.

You can try this instead:

```
h3 = {}
(h1.keys + h2.keys).uniq.each{|a| h3[a] = {"h1" => h1[a], "h2" => h2[a]}}
h3
# => {"a"=>{"h1"=>100, "h2"=>nil}, "b"=>{"h1"=>200, "h2"=>254}, "c"=>{"h1"=>nil, "h2"=>300}}
```

Comment: As an alternative to `(h1.keys + h2.keys).uniq`, you could also do `(h1.keys | h2.keys)`

Comment: @Ajedi32 yeah that even better. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 3):

The block is only invoked for duplicate keys. You can either ensure that both hashes contain all keys:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200, "c" => nil }
h2 = { "a" => nil, "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }

h1.merge(h2) { |k, val, old| { 'h1' => val, 'h2' => old } }
#=> {"a"=>{"h1"=>100, "h2"=>nil},
#    "b"=>{"h1"=>200, "h2"=>254},
#    "c"=>{"h1"=>nil, "h2"=>300}}
```

Or build a new hash yourself, e.g. using the keys from both hashes:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }

(h1.keys | h2.keys).map { |k| [k, { 'h1' => h1[k], 'h2' => h2[k] }] }.to_h
#=> {"a"=>{"h1"=>100, "h2"=>nil},
#    "b"=>{"h1"=>200, "h2"=>254},
#    "c"=>{"h1"=>nil, "h2"=>300}}
```

Comment: `(h1.keys + h2.keys).uniq` ⇒ `h1.keys | h2.keys`. Or even: `[h1,h2].map(&:keys).reduce(&:|)` :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that is somewhat general in terms of the numbers of hashes and hash labels:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h3 = { "c" => 111, "b" => 222 }
a = [h1,h2,h3]
labels = {h1=>"h1", h2=>"h2", h3=>"h3"}

h.reduce([]) { |keys,h| keys | h.keys }
 .each_with_object({}) { |k,h|
   h[k] = a.each_with_object({}) { |f,g| g[labels[f]] = f[k] } }
  #=> {"a"=>{"h1"=>100, "h2"=>nil, "h3"=>nil},
  #    "b"=>{"h1"=>200, "h2"=>254, "h3"=>222},
  #    "c"=>{"h1"=>nil, "h2"=>300, "h3"=>111}}
```

The steps:

```
keys = h.reduce([]) { |keys,h| keys | h.keys }
  #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
enum = keys.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["a", "b", "c"]:each_with_object({})> 
k,h = enum.next
  #=> ["a", {}] 
h[k] = a.each_with_object({}) { |f,g| g[labels[f]] = f[k] }
  #=> {"h1"=>100, "h2"=>nil, "h3"=>nil} 
k,h = enum.next
  #=> ["b", {"a"=>{"h1"=>100, "h2"=>nil, "h3"=>nil}}] 
h[k] = a.each_with_object({}) { |f,g| g[labels[f]] = f[k] }
  #=> {"h1"=>200, "h2"=>254, "h3"=>222} 
k,h = enum.next
  #=> ["c", {"a"=>{"h1"=>100, "h2"=>nil, "h3"=>nil},
  #    "b"=>{"h1"=>200, "h2"=>254, "h3"=>222}}] 
h[k] = a.each_with_object({}) { |f,g| g[labels[f]] = f[k] }
  #=> {"h1"=>nil, "h2"=>300, "h3"=>111} 
h
  #=> {"a"=>{"h1"=>100, "h2"=>nil, "h3"=>nil},
  #    "b"=>{"h1"=>200, "h2"=>254, "h3"=>222},
  #    "c"=>{"h1"=>nil, "h2"=>300, "h3"=>111}}
```